# fabric js set shadow to null after canvas render

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs, shadow

I am setting the shadow to fabric js rectangle using

```
o.setShadow("1px 1px 15px yellow");
```

Now the shadow is set to the respective rectangle where o is the current object But I regenerate the rectangle using a timeout after every 30 second the new rectangle gets generated but the shadow is still there on the old place so if rectangle no had shadow when the rectangle gets regenerated the shadow is still there but ideally all the shadows should be removed.

I tried

```
o.setShadow(null) and o.setShadow(0px 0px 0px) and canvas.renderAll()
```

But it does not work all the new rectangle does not have a shadow property has a shadow of null 
but the shadow is still there I need to remove the shadow altogether in the next iteration of  the settimeout. I Am using the 3.4.0 version of the Fabric js.

Comment: Can you create a snippet/fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zqpo1k8x/ I have created two rectangle with the same left and top so then new one should overlap and should not show any shadow but the shadow is still there.

Comment: You are adding shadow to the second rect object also. don't add it wont have any shadow.

Comment: If you want to remove shadow, you can do `object.shadow = null;`, [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xbspqzht/)

Comment: Durga If you remove the the shadow from the second rectangle it is still there

Comment: Durga I got it if you could post an answer I will accept as the right answer.

Comment: The fiddle I have given, works for you?

Comment: yes that and a tweak of my own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do `obj.shadow = null;` followed by `canvas#requestRenderAll`, it will remove the shadow of the object.

***DEMO***

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
const square = new fabric.Rect({
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  left: 50,
  top: 50,
  fill: '#000'
});
square.setShadow("1px 1px 15px yellow");
canvas.add(square);
setTimeout(() => {
  square.shadow = null;
  //or square.setShadow(null);
  canvas.requestRenderAll();
},1500);
```

```css
canvas {
  border : 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.4.0/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: I had the fabric js rectangle and I was creating more rectangle that was overlapping the previous one canvas.getObjects().forEach(function(o) { o.shadow=null;  });